# Javascript suddenly cannot find function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-deployment

I have a javascript function that takes two parameters `[TransferItem(@item.Id,@item.Tid)]`. My function has been executing per as normal but as of recent I'm suddenly getting:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: TransferItem is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick (index:397)

View call:

```
<input type="submit" 
       value="Transfer" 
       class="btn btn-success" 
       onclick="TransferItem(@item.Id,@item.Tid)" 
       id="transferButton" 
       data-url="@Url.Action("SubmitCart", "Cart")" />
```

My javascript function is not in a jquery `document.ready` function, it's just flat in my JavaScript file. I'm trying to avoid placing it in my view file as it will require me to repeat myself. How can I resolve this are they any test that I can do, anything?

Comment: Looks like TransferItem function isn't defined, where is it defined?

Comment: Did you add the reference of the js file on your shared view or the on the specific view itself?

Comment: show us where you add a reference to the js file and show us the contents of the js file. If it's just in a script section in the html and not in a js file, then show us the script section please

Comment: TransferItem is defined in my Javascript scripts.js file and all my reference to my javascript file is in my _Layout.cshtml that I have not changed.

Comment: if it "suddenly" stopped working, then you need to look for something which changed in between it working and not working. Also check whether the JS file is being loaded correctly in your page when it runs (use your browser's network tool to check that the JS file actually loaded into the page successfully) and that you don't have any console errors prior to that.